# Count values within moving matrix subset

Tags: r, matrix, subset

Say the following matrix

```
mat = round(matrix(runif(100), ncol = 5))
mat
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    1    0    1    0
 [2,]    0    0    1    1    1
 [3,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [4,]    1    0    1    0    1
 [5,]    1    0    0    1    1
 [6,]    1    0    0    1    1
 [7,]    1    0    1    1    1
 [8,]    1    1    1    0    1
 [9,]    0    0    0    1    0
[10,]    0    0    0    1    1
[11,]    0    0    0    0    0
[12,]    1    1    0    0    1
[13,]    1    1    0    1    0
[14,]    1    0    1    0    1
[15,]    0    1    1    0    0
[16,]    1    1    0    1    1
[17,]    1    1    1    0    1
[18,]    1    1    1    1    1
[19,]    0    1    0    0    1
[20,]    1    1    0    0    0
```

I want to generate a new matrix that would be the number of "1" within a 3x3 square subset around each cell of the original matrix.
e.g.

```
mat_sum
           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
    [1,]    1    2    4    4    3
    [2,]    3    5    6    7    5
    [3,]    3    6    6    8    5
    etc.
```

I have tried with the following loop, but it does not give what I need

```
for(x in 1:(nrow(mat)-3)){
    for (y in 1:(ncol(mat)-3)){
        mat2[x,y] = sum(mat[c(x:x+2), c(y:y+2)] == 1))
}}
```

I need to be able to extend the subset to a 10x10 box on my data (> 1000x1000 cells). Any hint is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#DATA
set.seed(42)
mat = round(matrix(runif(20), ncol = 5))
mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
#[2,]    1    1    1    0    0
#[3,]    0    1    0    0    0
#[4,]    1    0    1    1    1
```

For each element in `ith` row and `jth` column, get sum of elements in a matrix within `i-1` to `i+1` row and `j-1` to `j+1` column. If the values are out of bounds, replace with minimum or maximum index as necessary.

```
t(sapply(1:NROW(mat), function(i)
    sapply(1:NCOL(mat), function(j)
        sum(mat[max(1, i-1):min(NROW(mat), i+1), max(1, j-1):min(NCOL(mat), j + 1)]))))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    4    6    5    4    2
#[2,]    5    7    6    4    2
#[3,]    4    6    5    4    2
#[4,]    2    3    3    3    2
```

Comment: thanks d.b but I don't get the same table as you do.. :-/

Comment: ah indeed not! I forgot that runif gives a random dataset each time ;-) it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to write a function that gets the neighbors, and then take the sum.

```
set.seed(42)

mat = round(matrix(runif(100), ncol = 5))
mat_sum = matrix(nrow=20, ncol=5)

for(x in seq_len(nrow(mat))) {
  for (y in seq_len(ncol(mat))) {
    mat_sum[x,y] <- sum(getNeighbors(x, y, mat))
  }
}

getNeighbors <- function(x, y, mat) {
  unlist(mat[((x-2):(x)) %% nrow(mat) + 1, ((y-2):(y)) %% ncol(mat) + 1])
}
```

You don't need to compare to 1, because sum(1, 1, 0) is the same as sum(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE).

Comment: thanks ConCave, I understand what you are proposing. The only issue is when the cell is on an edge. The subset is incomplete and gets completed with the values on the other side of the matrix

Comment: I see now that that's not the intended behavior -- I had only looked at the top-right corner and didn't see that they weren't supposed to wrap around because there were lots of zeroes on the bottom. Fixing my answer now.